# Render "namespaced" component react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm currently using React with a Rails 5.2.0 application, with the react-rails gem.

To keep a clean distribution of files, I want to store them within their specific folder, and for that I want to namespace the components I'm going to need.

The gem's implementation works well and I can render the trivial GreetUser component without problem. The challenge comes when I want to add a namespace, and I'm not really sure if React, react-component (helper) or any other supports it (as Rails would do it).

My attempt trying to render a Policies component:

```
# view
<%= react_component 'Policies.Policies' %>

# component
# app/javascripts/components/policies/Policies.js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class Policies extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <h1>I'm watching you</h1>
    <div>
  }
}
```

And I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module './Policies'.
ReferenceError: Policies is not defined
Uncaught Error: Cannot find component: 'Policies.Policies'. Make sure your component is available to render.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the view you should use slashes (`/`) not dots in the namespace:

   `<%= react_component 'Policies/Policies' %>`
2. Your `Policies` directory should be capitalized:

   `app/javascripts/components/Policies/Policies.js`

Should work

Comment: You're completely right!. It works at what level? Javascript, es6, React or what?, I saw some approaches creating window classes and then specifying the inheritance.